# Boost function and boost lambda

Tags: c++, function, boost, lambda

I've seen a few related questions, but am still just puzzled.  What's wrong with this syntax:

```
boost::function<int (int)> g = f;
boost::function<int (int)> g2 = 2*g(boost::lambda::_1);
```

I've tried it with boost 1.35 and 1.38 (these are the two installations I have lying around) on gcc 4.3.4, and they both give variations of the error:

```
no match for call to '(boost::function<int ()(int)>) (const boost::lambda::lambda_functor<boost::lambda::placeholder<1> >&)'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't call a function with a placeholder directly. You have to [use `bind`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/lambda/le_in_details.html#lambda.bind_expressions).

```
boost::function<int (int)> g2 = 2 * boost::lambda::bind(g, boost::lambda::_1);
```

([Example](http://ideone.com/EGUZv))

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you give up `Boost.Lambda` as it’s out of date. The compiler which supports C++0x provides native lambda and is easier to understand. You can use GCC with 4.4 or higher version, Visual Studio 2010 also supports C++0x.